# If I have a table inside a table, can their borders collapse?

Tags: css

The JS Fiddle is located here: http://jsfiddle.net/apyh2b4x/ It is using the Twitter Bootstrap, as am I in my project.

The HTML code is very simple, the gist of it is having a `table` inside a `table`:

```
<div style="padding:20px;">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td>Outside label</td>
            <td>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Inside label 1</td>
                        <td>Inside label 2</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

What I am wondering is, is it possible for the `borders` of these two tables to `collapse`, the same way as the `borders` of two joint cells in the same table are collapsing?

Comment: Collapse doesn't seem to work, but here's an elegant solution for the previous comment by @will-jenkins (to add all borders, then remove the outer ones for the inner table).  In brief, this sets css for `table tr:first-child td`, `table tr td:first-child`, etc. [A Table With Borders Only On The Inside](https://css-tricks.com/table-borders-inside/)

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to collapse your borders or remove the padding and margin?

If the latter (or both), it's pretty straightforward:

```
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
table, tr, td{
    padding:0 !important;
    margin:0 !important;

}
```

see here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apyh2b4x/2/)

Comment: That's not collapsed, that only removes the paddings. See how the last two cells have duplicate borders (as if it's a `2px` border)? Collapsing them would make it into a single `1px` border. That's what I want to know if it's possible with tables inside tables. Because it is possible with cells inside the same table to collapse their borders (which is the default Bootstrap's `.table` behavior).

Comment: ah, in that case I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I guess all you can do is totally remove the borders on the inside table and then add back in the ones you want... like: http://jsfiddle.net/apyh2b4x/4/

tbh... tables within tables are not a good idea imho

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/apyh2b4x/3/)**

CSS:

```
.table {
    border-collapse:collapse !important;
    padding: 0px 0px !important;
    margin:0 !important;
    text-indent:10px;
}
.table-condensed>thead>tr>th, .table-condensed>tbody>tr>th, .table-condensed>tfoot>tr>th, .table-condensed>thead>tr>td, .table-condensed>tbody>tr>td, .table-condensed>tfoot>tr>td {
    padding: 0px 0px !important;
    border-top:none;
    line-height:30px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="padding:20px;">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Outside label</td>
                <td>
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Inside label 1</td>
                            <td>Inside label 2</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```